# If $V\cap f(X)\neq \phi$, $W\cap f(X)\neq \phi$, $f(X)\subseteq V\cup W$ and $f$ is continuous, is it true that $f^{-1}(V)\cup f^{-1}(W)=X$?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let

$$
f:X\rightarrow Y
$$

be a continuous function.

If $V\cap f(X)\neq \phi$ and $W\cap f(X)\neq \phi$ and  $f(X)\subseteq V\cup W$, is it true that $f^{-1}(V)\cup f^{-1}(W)=X$?

If it is true, then why? because I could understand if $X\subseteq f^{-1}(V)\cup f^{-1}(W)$ but I am not sure why $f^{-1}(V)\cup f^{-1}(W)=X$?

Comment: Excuse my english. Do you understand why $X\subseteq f^{-1}(V)\cup f^{-1}(W)$?

Comment: @sinbadh, I think so.

Comment: Ok. The other contention is trivial cause domain of $f$ is $X$. Then $f^{-1}(U)\subseteq X$ and the same for $f^{-1}(V)$. Indeed, note that all the proof uses only hypotesis $f(X)\subseteq V\cup W$ (for example, continuity not is a usefull hypothesis)

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in X$ be any point.  Then since $f(x)\in f(X)\subseteq V\cup W$, either $f(x)\in V$ or $f(x)\in W$.  This means exactly that $x\in f^{-1}(V)$ or $x\in f^{-1}(W)$, which means that $x\in f^{-1}(V)\cup f^{-1}(W)$.  This shows that $X\subseteq f^{-1}(V)\cup f^{-1}(W)$.

The other direction $f^{-1}(V)\cup f^{-1}(W)\subseteq X$ is true by definition, since $f^{-1}(V)$ and $f^{-1}(W)$ are defined to be certain subsets of $X$.  That is, the definition of $f^{-1}(V)$ is $\{x\in X:f(x)\in V\}$, so by definition every element of $f^{-1}(V)$ is an element of $X$.  Similarly every element of $f^{-1}(W)$ is an element of $X$.